# T-SQL stored procedure date variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have this T-SQL stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.datealter 
    @LastChangeDate AS date 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        s.[DivNo]as Division,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.Date = @LastChangeDate 
                   THEN s.SELLINC ELSE 0 END) ActualSales
    FROM 
        [dbo].[NewLayerReports] s 
    WHERE 
        s.BRN = 1
    GROUP BY 
        s.[DivNo]
END
GO
```

When I execute this it works ok.

I am using this stored procedure in a SSRS report. When I execute the SSRS report, it asks me to enter or pick the date.

Here always I wanted a calendar to show last year current month. For example, If I run the report on November 2016 the calendar should show Nov 2015.

How can we do this please?

In SSRS parameter, if I set default value then, I couldn't edit the date value. Please see the picture,

[image]

Comment: So you want the default value of the `Last Change Date` parameter to be this day but in the previous year?

Comment: @iamdave No, I want user to pick the date. So date will vary.

Comment: The date picker will initially show the default value and then any date the user picks.  You cannot have the user pick one date and then display another whilst still using the date picker.  If you just want to display the relative date, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can give default value to your parameter. Give expression in your default value for parameter as `Date.Now.Date.AddYears(-1)`. It will show same month in previous year when you run the report.

Comment: This answer would work if you want to do it using SSRS Parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the default value of a parameter in SSRS, right click on the Parameter and select Properties.  In the Default Value screen you can set the expression that returns the date.

To get this day last year, you can use: 
`=today.AddYears(-1)`

Though if you want the start of the month you also need to add the days as well:
`=today.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1-today.day())`

---

If appears you just want to display the date relative to the one the user picked.  In that case you can use the above expressions as required within a report element (such as a title at the top of the report), but replace any instance of `today` with `Parameters!ParameterName.Value`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to set default date. Because User can't edit the date. I just wanted to show last year calendar (so that user no need click numerous back button in calendar to reach last year) and User needs to pick the date.  I have uploaded the screen shot in my question.

Comment: @user2331670  In your comparison date parameter you can set the default as per my expressions above, but reference the Primary parameter.  If the purpose of this is simply to display the dates, you are going about this entirely the wrong way.  And in relation to "If I set the default value I couldn't edit the value"  yes you certainly can.  Are you setting the Available Values field by mistake?

Comment: Yes, My main aim is to simply display the last year dates, so user can pick as their requirements. How can I achieve this please?

Comment: @user2331670  You can only have that parameter show the date that the user picks.  If they ***need*** to select the previous year, then they can just type in the date they need instead of using the picker.  Given your Parameter names and what your stored procedure does, I think you have larger problems than how the report looks at the moment though, as your parameters suggest a date range, but your procedure pulls out one day's worth of values.

Comment: @user2331670  In addition, simply set the default value per my answer above and when the user selects the date picker, it will show the default value of last year anyway.  You can completely wrong when you say setting a default value prevents the user from changing the date value.